# Vim recording (q) can't record line deleting (d)

Tags: vim, ide

In <kbd>q</kbd> mode I press the following combination:

<kbd>home</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd>
(delete current line and step 3 lines down)

Then I exit from recording mode by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>. Then I try to use recorded sequence to delete each 4rd line. So I press <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to replay my register "1". I watch expected behaviour only once. The second start of register "1" (<kbd>@</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> again) lead to cursor just moving 2 symbols right. My recorded program is forgotten.

Any other program without the command <kbd>d</kbd> works perfectly and may be repeated any number of times. So, how to record a program with <kbd>d</kbd> (delete line) operator?

Comment: what's your key sequence to record the macro? `q<what?>[Home]djjjq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim uses register `1-9` for deleted text. Latest deleted text is in reg `1`, When another delete happens. The text in `1` got moved to reg `2` and reg `1` holds the latest delete and so on. More details `:help quote_number`

So your recording got overwritten after one replay.

As a good practice, when recording it is preferable to use `named registers` i.e. `a-z Or A -Z`. These are not filled until we instruct. More details `:help quote_alpha`

My normal practice is to use reg `a`, quite near to `q` key, for recording. For your particular example, I would simply use

```
qa
djjj
q
@a
```

Then continue to replay the recording.